# Use openrowset function in sql server 2005 (x86) on Windows server 2008 (x64)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to access xls file from the disk from sql server stored proc, it is working perfectly in dev. enviornment (win xp (x86) / SQL server 2008) but it provides me error as

Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 64-bit Jet OLE DB Provider.  From [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedack/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=123311):

> The behavior you described is
>   expected. If your application runs in
>   64-bit mode, all of the components it
>   uses must also be 64-bit. There is no
>   64-bit Jet OLE DB Provider, so you get
>   the message described. You would
>   receive a similar error when trying to
>   connect to a database using OLE DB or
>   ODBC if there is no 64-bit version of
>   the specified OLE DB provider or ODBC
>   driver.

You can install a 32-bit version of Sql Server on a 64-bit Windows operating system.  The 32-bit version would be able to use the JET OLE DB provider.

To my surprise, I have been unable to find an alternative OLE DB driver that allows you to read Excel files in 64 bit mode.  Hopefully I'm missing something, this would be a failure nearing 1.0 on the Vista scale.

Comment: In 64-bit, there's neither an ODBC nor OLEDB version of JET.  I wouldn't expect a bridge from OLEDB to ODBC to fix that.